# 2D Ising Model - Metropolis Algorithm:

Tags: python, montecarlo

I have tried to code the 2D Ising Model with the Metropolis Algorithm trying to calculate the energy and specific heat depending on beta (which is the inverse temperature). But comparing my result to the exact result given, I find that my results are wrong:[Energy - beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhugw.png) and [Specific-heat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mOpI.png). The green curve is the exact solution, the dotted line my attempt.

I have tried changing parameters but I have the feeling I did something wrong in my code. I would appreciate if someone could point out (or even explain) what I did wrong. I would be very thankful as I am kind of new to programming MC-Simulations.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# settings
L = 8
beta_steps = 50
beta_start = 0.3
beta_end = 0.6
equilibrium_steps = 10 ** 3
# random.seed(1)

sweeps = 10 ** 5

energy_averages = []
mag_averages = []
energy_diffs = []
cvs = []
betas = []

# ------ FUNCTIONS ------
def energy_of_site(site):
    y = site[0]
    x = site[1]
    spin = lattice[y][x]
    left = lattice[y][x - 1]
    right = lattice[y][(x + 1) % L]
    above = lattice[y - 1][x]
    below = lattice[(y + 1) % L][x]

    energy = spin * (left + right + above + below)
    return energy/4


def total_energy_f():
    total_energy_local = 0
    for i in range(L):
        for j in range(L):
            total_energy_local = total_energy_local + energy_of_site([i, j])
    return total_energy_local



def flipping_judge(energy_diff):
    if energy_diff <= 0:
        return True
    else:
        if random.random() < np.exp(-beta * energy_diff):
            return True
        else:
            #print(energy_diff, np.exp(-beta * energy_diff))
            return False


# ------ MAIN CODE ------
beta = beta_start
for b in range(beta_steps+1):
    print(b, beta)
    betas.append(beta)
    # setup
    energies = []

    # creating new lattice
    lattice = []
    for i in range(L):
        row = []
        for j in range(L):
            #row.append(random.randrange(-1, 2, 2))     #random lattice
            row.append(1)                               #lattie with all 1
        lattice.append(row)

    total_energy = total_energy_f()

    for i in range(sweeps + equilibrium_steps):

        # select random site
        site = [random.randint(0, L - 1), random.randint(0, L - 1)]
        y = site[0]
        x = site[1]

        # calculate energy difference
        E0 = energy_of_site(site)
        lattice[y][x] = -1 * lattice[y][x]
        energy_diff = 2 * (energy_of_site(site) - E0)

        #energy_diffs.append(energy_diff)

        if flipping_judge(energy_diff):
            total_energy = total_energy + energy_diff
            # keep the changed lattice / accept flip
            if i > equilibrium_steps:
                energies.append(total_energy / (L**2))
                #mags.append(abs(np.sum(lattice) / (L ** 2)))
        else:
            # change the lattice back / dont accept the flip
            lattice[y][x] = -1 * lattice[y][x]
            total_energy = total_energy
            energies.append(total_energy / (L ** 2))
    #plt.plot(energies)
    #plt.show()


    if len(energies) == 0:
        print(energies)
        break
    energy_average = sum(energies) / len(energies)
    energy_averages.append(-energy_average)
    #mag_averages.append(sum(mags) / len(mags))

    energy_variance = 0
    for j in energies:
        energy_variance = energy_variance + ((j - energy_average) ** 2)
    cv = energy_variance / len(energies)
    cvs.append(cv)



    beta = beta + ((beta_end - beta_start) / beta_steps)


#import exact solution

file = open("8_en.txt", "r")
og_beta = []
og_energy = []

for line in file:
    fields = line.split("  ")
    og_beta.append(float(fields[1]))
    og_energy.append(float(fields[2]))
file.close()

file = open("8_cv.txt", "r")
og_betacv = []
og_cv = []

for line in file:
    fields = line.split("  ")
    og_betacv.append(float(fields[1]))
    og_cv.append(float(fields[2]))
file.close()



#plt.plot(energies, ".")
#plt.ylabel('energies')
#plt.show()

#plot stuff
plt.plot(betas, energy_averages, "b.", og_beta, og_energy, "g.")
plt.ylabel('energy_averages')
plt.show()
plt.plot(betas, cvs, ".", og_betacv, og_cv, "g.")
plt.ylabel('cvs')
plt.show()
```

Kind regards, Joey

Comment: This would be better fit on code review. BTW, there are multiple implementations of a 2D Ising on google.

Comment: How about replacing `l[y - 1][x]` with `l[max(y - 1,0)][x]`, same for x ?